# Random layout rooms with intersecting walls

Tags: tiles, procedural-generation, maps

I am trying to layout few rectangle rooms on un unlimited map. The main condition is that every next room has to intersect with one of already placed with at least one point of the wall.

[image: Smth like that]

The number, width and height are random values generated by something like D&D dice rolling. Every next room can be adjacent to any placed rooms. 
Result should look like a kind of dungeon (hope the picture makes it more clear)
[image: Maybe that picture makes it clear]

I am afraid that different packing algorithms too heavy for that problem. I would greatly appreciate any advice!

Comment: Can you freely decide the number, width and height of the rooms or are these fixed? And what exactly are your aesthetic requirements? The trivial solution would to just place the rooms in a line, but something tells me that's not the solution you are looking for.

Comment: And what do you mean with "one of already placed". Do all rooms need to be adjacent to the first or can they be adjacent to *any* already placed room?

Comment: The number, width and height are random values. Every room can be adjacent to any placed rooms. And yes, you are right, I need more aesthetic solution than just a line. The result should look like dungeon,  I think, with more than one possible way to go through it

Comment: Random values generated by your algorithm or generated by someone else? "not one way to go through" means the room-graph needs to have circles and can not be just a tree. This makes the problem far more complicated. I think you should [edit your question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/117068/edit) and elaborate on your exact requirements.

Comment: Without knowing more of your requirements, a [BSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) algorithm is one of **many** that could [get you close](http://codepen.io/xgundam05/pen/aerBJ).

Comment: Thanks @XGundam05, I've read about BSP, but it is commonly used to generate rooms which connected with hallways. So in my case I did not get how to be sure that room are adjacent to any other room.

Comment: Also, it seems that after leafs generation one should place a room into  each leaf to keep rooms connected, but what if I need certain number of rooms, which leafs I can safely skip without getting orphan rooms?

Comment: @OlyaKusaeva **one** way would be that provided rectangular rooms, you can just use the leaves themselves. And given a required N rooms, stop generation at N leaves.

Comment: @XGundam05 sorry, but I don't understand yet. Let's say I generate binary tree of N leafs and each leaf equals a room. But how can I apply any constraints such as min and max size of the room or for example specify sizes of rooms player enters level and exits?

Comment: What do you mean by "unlimited map"? According to your picture, it actually seems that you need the rooms to fit within a limited map, i.e. within specif boundaries given a priori.

Comment: @MAnd I mean that I don't specify any boundaries of resulting dungeon, but also I don't want rooms were lined up

Comment: @OlyaKusaeva let's take this over to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36094/random-layout-rooms-with-intersecting-walls)

Comment: @XGundam05 Unfortunately, I have not enough reputation to chat, but I read you advices and thanks!  I will continue researching information you've provide

Comment: i was thinking of: keep a list of rooms that you can add to, create a new room and pick a room to connect to from the list, pick an edge from that room and try to place the new room along that edge, if successful remove the selected room and add the new room n times, if unsuccesful pick another edge or room to attach to repeat until the desired number of rooms is reached.

Comment: @user2645227 Hi, I was thinking about it too. I like the idea of having a list of pre-generated rooms to layout, it seems more simple and intuitive. But what about, hmm, performance? Is such naive algorithm acceptable in game development? I am afraid of stucking at some moment if assumed that a room can be connected with more than two anothers. And I think I don't understand the part about "remove selected room" – is it means that max of connections for a room is two, as enter and exit?

Comment: Remove selected room means that you remove the room from the set of rooms available to connect to. The new room will always have an entrance (the exit of the room you connect to) and up to n exits where n is the number of times you add it to your list, you could add larger rooms more often or determine n randomly. The naive implementation might be a bit sluggish but i think you can optimize it by keeping track of which edges are unlikely to have valid spots for example..

Comment: @user2645227 Now I see. Thank you, I think your way is the best to start with in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very rough algorithm:

1. Create a temporary room
2. Check if the position of the room is allowed
3. Move the room if necessary

The first two are relatively simple, the last one you have to make you own algorithm that suits the layout you prefer.

The following java code produce a level where

1. The room is a Rectangle object
2. If the Rectangle intersects any existing rectangle, it is forbidden, otherwise allowed.
3. The room is moved counter clockwise in a circle, where the circle's diameter is increase with 1 pixel each revolution - this makes the room placement adjacent to existing rooms. (I think there might be some refinement needed, but the general idea seems to work).

(I've just started to learn java, so if you're experience with that you can likely find some better way to achieve the same results)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class GenerateLevel {
    private ArrayList<Rectangle> Rooms = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    private Random r = new Random();
    private BufferedImage levelImage;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new GenerateLevel();
    }

    public GenerateLevel(){
        Rooms.add(new Rectangle(500,500,10 + r.nextInt(50), 10 + r.nextInt(50)));
        int numberOfRooms = 30;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRooms; i++){
            addRectangle(50 + r.nextInt(30), 50 + r.nextInt(30));
        }

        levelImage = new BufferedImage(1000, 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        drawImage(levelImage);
        //Writes the BufferedImage levelImage to the level.png file.
        try {
            ImageIO.write(levelImage, "png", new File("src/res/level.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ImageIO.write exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Draws the final level into the BufferedImage levelImage.
    private void drawImage(BufferedImage levelImage) {
        Graphics2D drawGraphics = levelImage.createGraphics();

        for(Rectangle room:Rooms){
            drawGraphics.setColor(new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255)));
            drawGraphics.fill(room);
            drawGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            drawGraphics.draw(room);

        }

    }

    //Adds a rectangle to the ArrayList Rooms.
    private void addRectangle(int width, int height){
        int[] position = findAllowedPosition(width, height);
        Rooms.add(new Rectangle(position[0], position[1], width, height));
    }

    //Finds an allowed position by scanning clockwise and increasing the scan diameter.
    private int[] findAllowedPosition(int width, int height){
        boolean positionFound = false;
        boolean intersectionFound = false;
        int radiusCounter = 1;
        int scanCounter = 0;

        Rectangle tempRect = new Rectangle(500, 500, width, height);

        int[] origin = {500, 500};
        int[] lastPosition = {500, 500};
        while(!positionFound){

            //Check if tempRect intersects with any already placed rectangles.
            intersectionFound = false;
            for(Rectangle r : Rooms){
                if (r.intersects(tempRect))
                {
                    intersectionFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //If tempRect intersects any rectangle, move tempRect.
            if (intersectionFound){

                if(scanCounter == 0){
                    lastPosition[1]--;
                }

                lastPosition = scanClockwise(radiusCounter, origin, lastPosition);
                scanCounter++;
                tempRect.setLocation(lastPosition[0], lastPosition[1]);
            } 
            //If tempRect doesn't intersect any rectangle, set PositionFound = true;
            else {
                positionFound = true;
                break;
            }

            //Check if one revolution of the scan radius has been performed, if so, increase scanRadius.
            if(((radiusCounter * 2-1)*4 + 4) < scanCounter){
                radiusCounter++;
                scanCounter = 0;
            }
        }
        int[] foundPosition = {(int)tempRect.getX(), (int)tempRect.getY()};
        return foundPosition;
    }

    private int[] scanClockwise(int scanRadius, int[] origin, int[] lastPosition){
        int[] returnArray = lastPosition;

        // Upper line of the scan rectangle
        if (lastPosition[0] >= origin[0] - scanRadius && lastPosition[0] < origin[0] + scanRadius && lastPosition[1] == origin[1] - scanRadius){
            returnArray[0]++;
        } 
        // Right line of the scan rectangle
        else if (lastPosition[1] >= origin[1] - scanRadius && lastPosition[1] < origin[1] + scanRadius && lastPosition[0] == origin[0] + scanRadius){
            returnArray[1]++;
        }
        // Bottom  line of the scan rectangle
        else if (lastPosition[0] <= origin[0] + scanRadius && lastPosition[0] > origin[0] - scanRadius && lastPosition[1] == origin[1] + scanRadius){
            returnArray[0]--;
        }
        // Left line of the scan rectangle
        else {
            returnArray[1]--;
        }
        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

Below is a picture made by this code, but point 3 above is where you'll have to write an algorithm that suits whatever level-layout you have in mind.
[image: level.png]